# Java- ToString() in a Java Bean generated with Hibernate caused StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new in this forum so I hope I havent't done anything wrong..
I've started learning Java one month ago and I have a little problem.
I've got 2 entities and I want to print the CD with its tracks but I have this exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

I have no idea how to correct this problem..
I post the code and the entities:

TbTrack

```
package it.tgi.cd.entities2;

// default package
// Generated 11-mag-2015 16.29.34 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * TbTrack generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_track", catalog = "db_cd_store")
public class TbTrack implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idTrack;
    private TbCd tbCd;
    private String title;

    public TbTrack() {
    }

    public TbTrack(TbCd tbCd, String title) {
        this.tbCd = tbCd;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "idTrack=" + idTrack + ", tbCd=" + tbCd + ", title=" + title;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_track", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdTrack() {
        return this.idTrack;
    }

    public void setIdTrack(Integer idTrack) {
        this.idTrack = idTrack;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cd", nullable = false)
    public TbCd getTbCd() {
        return this.tbCd;
    }

    public void setTbCd(TbCd tbCd) {
        this.tbCd = tbCd;
    }

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

TbCd

```
package it.tgi.cd.entities2;

// default package
// Generated 11-mag-2015 16.29.34 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * TbCd generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_cd", catalog = "db_cd_store")
public class TbCd implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idCd;
    private String title;
    private Set<TbTrack> tbTracks = new HashSet<TbTrack>(0);

    public TbCd() {
    }

    public TbCd(int idCd, String title) {
        this.idCd = idCd;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "idCd=" + idCd + ", title=" + title + ", track= " + tbTracks;
    }

    public TbCd(int idCd, String title, Set<TbTrack> tbTracks) {
        this.idCd = idCd;
        this.title = title;
        this.tbTracks = tbTracks;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_cd", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdCd() {
        return this.idCd;
    }

    public void setIdCd(int idCd) {
        this.idCd = idCd;
    }

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tbCd")
    public Set<TbTrack> getTbTracks() {
        return this.tbTracks;
    }

    public void setTbTracks(Set<TbTrack> tbTracks) {
        this.tbTracks = tbTracks;
    }

}
```

CDDAO2

```
package it.tgi.cd.dao2;

import it.tgi.cd.connection2.DBConnection2;
import it.tgi.cd.entities2.TbCd;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class CDDAO2 {
    public static void searchCD(String title) {
        Session session = DBConnection2.openConnection();
        String query = "FROM TbCd where title='" + title + "'";
        Query _query = session.createQuery(query);
        List<TbCd> list = _query.list();
        System.out.println(list);

        DBConnection2.closeConnection(session);

    }

}
```

Can you help me please?
Thank You!

Comment: can you add the stack trace?

Comment: On which line do you get the stack overflow? This is usually caused by recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the CD *string* in your track class, and you are adding all track *strings* in your CD class.

This is an infinite recursion: A CD string contains a track string (among others), this track string contains the CD string (the same with which it started!), which in turn contains again the track string, and so on

Solution is to either not include the tracks in the method `TbCd.toString()` or to not include the CD in the method `TbTrack.toString()`. I would suggest the latter, as it might be intended to have all tracks included when assembling the CD string:

```
public class TbCd implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "idCd=" + idCd + ", title=" + title + ", track= " + tbTracks;
    }
}

public class TbTrack implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "idTrack=" + idTrack + ", title=" + title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, when you do:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "idCd=" + idCd + ", title=" + title + ", track= " + tbTracks;
}
```

It tries to print your set of TbTrack Objects, which also overrides the toString method so:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "idTrack=" + idTrack + ", tbCd=" + tbCd + ", title=" + title;
}
```

So whats happen:

It prints the list of tracks, every tracks toString method is called which prints the CD again "tbCD" which tries to print the tracks again and again and again and again uupps STACKOVERFLOW Reached!!!

Remove "tbCD= +tbCD" from the toString of your TbTrack class and all is fine. Instead print the titel for example ;)

Simple fix would be:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "idTrack=" + idTrack + ", tbCd.Title=" + tbCd.title + ", title=" + title;
}
```